# How can I get cell (x, y) position from QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt5

I am trying to get QCalendarWidget's Cell position.
from the upper image, it's cell position must be tuple: (2,4)

[image]

I would also appreciate if I can get the cell date and find it's position on another library.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QCalendarWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
        cal.setGridVisible(True)
        cal.clicked[QDate].connect(self.showDate)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        date = cal.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(cal)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('QCalendarWidget')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
        self.show()

    def showDate(self, date):
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I've uploaded it. I've done getting cell's datetime. However I don't know how to get the cell position row, col.

Comment: Why do you need that tuple?

Comment: https://camping.gtdc.or.kr/DZ_reservation/reserCamping_v3.php?xch=reservation&xid=camping_reservation'

Comment: Also why won't you calculate it by the days in a month?

Comment: I have this website and I need to click specific date and course.

Comment: In order to do my wish, I need to know the position of the date

Comment: How can I calculate it by the days and get (x, y)

Comment: @Kateshim If you don't agree with the closure for a [post of yours marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73013512/2001654), then don't delete it and ask again the same question, but ***explain*** why you don't agree. That said, the answer for which yours was considered duplicate explains ***exactly*** what you're asking, so this post is *again* unjustified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ok, I'm sorry, my code didn't meet your demand.

Here you are.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QCalendarWidget, QTableView
from PyQt6.QtCore import QDate, Qt, QModelIndex

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.cal.setGridVisible(True)
        self.cal.clicked[QDate].connect(self.showDate)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        date = self.cal.selectedDate()
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.cal)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('QCalendarWidget')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
        self.show()

        

    def showDate(self, date):
        self.lbl.setText(date.toString())

   
        child = self.findChild(QTableView)       
        
        c = child.currentIndex()
        data = child.model().data(c)

        print(c.column() , c.row())              
  
        
       
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Explanation**

`QCalendarWidget` is made from some widgets containing `QTableView`.
So we get the `QTableView` by findChild method.
If you click the tile of QTableView, the index is fixed.
The index has  row, column.

this solution is a little dirty, but better.

<sub>I delete my previous answer.</sub>

Comment: Well, using the code you wrote, I faced some problem. Some cells aren't matching the position. for example, the day 25 must be (5,2) but (4,2)

Comment: @Kate shim I updated my answer. If you like my answer, please upvote^^.

Comment: Oh my god ><; this question is closed!